# php to look for string in address bar, then replace in-body snippet with hard value 1 or 2

Tags: php, html

Hi apologies for the non educated terms, and redundancy in explanation (complete newb)...

...I am looking for the php "header" code and in-html-body-phpsnippet which will look for an exact string such as "tid" **in the address bar**, and modify the output of the `<phpsnippet>` *based on "tid" being in the address bar or not*

--> **IF yes "tid" is present**, then replace entire  `<phpsnippet>` within html body with predetermined hard value such as "http://google.com"

-->**IF NOT** present, then replace entire `<phpsnippet>` in html body with a different hard value, such as "http://failblog.org"

What would the header script and also the in-body `<phpsnippet>` be?

VALUE1 (http://google.com) and VALUE2 (http://failblog.org) would be hard values that I would define in the header script , presumably)

**My goal is to change the target URL a visitor is given within links on my page based on whether or not a "tid" parameter has been passed along with them or not**

thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I get what you are asking...
I would do it like this.

```
$booltid = false; //create Boolean to determine if 'tid', declare it false  
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //store the current url request as a string  
$string = 'tid';//create string you want to search for  
if (strpos($url,$string)){  
   $booltid=true;} //if 'tid' is present change Boolean to true
```

in html body

```
if ($booltid){  
   $name='Google'; //if 'tid' link name
   $link='http://google.com';} //if 'tid' link
if(!$booltid){
   $name='FailBlog'; //if no 'tid' link name
   $link='http://failblog.org';} //if no 'tid' link  

echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$name.'</a>'; //print link
```

hope that's what you meant

Or of course you could shorten it to something like this if it suits you better

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'tid')){     
   echo '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>';}
else{  
   echo '<a href="http://failblog.org">FailBlog</a>';}
```

Comment: Kickass, worked. (I went with the shortened string within html body). Somebody get this man a steak dinner.